# Unity - SerializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties() using relavant property setting method

Tags: c#, unity, serialization

The problem I have is this.
I have an editor script, at the end of OnInspectorGUI() I want to apply all the changes with the serialized object.
The simplest way to show my problem is thus:

```
[SerializeField]
private bool _property;
public bool property
{
    get { return _property; }
    set
    {
        _property = value;
        //do some amazing stuff
    }
}
```

---

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    serializedObject.Update();
    prop = serializedObject.FindProperty("_property");
    //blah blah blah
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

But in order to do my special amazing code represented by the comment 'do some amazing stuff', I have to copy and paste the code or do away with the gets & sets entirely, opting instead for some kind of post-update, all-in-one refresh function.
Ideally, I want to tell SerializedObject, 'Hey, don't do _property = value, do property = value instead!'
Pretty sure that's not possible though, so what should I do instead?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity serialization so I'll leave a comment instead of answer. You want custom (de)serialization which can be done by [implementing ISerializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1). If that interface is not supported in Unity, there's an [ISerializationCallbackReceiver](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html) interface you can implement, but this is called after deserialization so you have less control on what custom actions are possible (but may work for your scenario).